# Restrict mobile application on App Store

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, cordova

I'm developing a mobile application which we would like to restrict the access. I'm using Phonegap Build and setting the configuration on the `config.xml` file. There's a property named `target-device` (only applied to iOS) that can be set to `handset`, `tablet` or `universal` and it should block the app installation depending on the device.

Setting it to `handset` alows the application to run on both smartphone and tablet devices but this is not what I want. Is this behavior the same on the App Store or does it restrict only to smartphones?

**EDIT: this issue only applies to iOS devices**

Comment: is your project contain AndroidManifest.xml file , if yes then you can restrict by giving support-screen values in that

Comment: You can always restrict and filter wich devices you don't want to be exposed to your app availability using the manual configuration in Google Play Developers Console. Check this: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=go&answer=1286017

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `config.xml` file that your talking about is for PhoneGap Build, which is different to regular `PhoneGap` (now `Cordova`).

As per their documentation on PhoneGap Build config.xml, it states that the `target-device` setting only applies to iOS builds, so this setting will not be used for your Android build.

https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

> ```
> target-device with possible values handset, tablet, or universal
>      example: <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
>      please note that this currently only applies to iOS builds; by default all builds are universal
> ```

I think your best bet is to use Eclipse, Android SDK, etc. and PhoneGap (Corvoda) rather than the PhoneGap Build service, as it will give you the control you want. For setup instructions see:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android